# GoogleDrive内でGoogleAppsScriptによる大きいファイルサイズのファイルコピーに失敗する

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-sdk

下記のGoogleAppsScriptを使おうとすると，コピーの部分で失敗します。
IDがAAAというフォルダ以下の全フォルダ・ファイルをIDがBBBというフォルダにコピーし，コピー処理終了後にAAAというフォルダ以下のフォルダ・ファイルをすべてゴミ箱へ移動させるスクリプトになっています。

IDがAAAというフォルダのファイル・フォルダをIDがBBBというフォルダにコピーしようとすると，途中で「上限を超えています: DriveApp（行 19、ファイル「コード」）」というエラーが出て，一部のみコピーされて大部分はコピーに失敗します。

行19は，「file.makeCopy(file.getName(), dest);」が該当します。

コピー元ファイルは映像ファイルなので，1ファイル2Gbyte程度，一日100ファイル程度になります。
一日一度，GoogleDrive内で別フォルダに移動させようとしています。

なお対象フォルダを変更して，小さなファイル(PDF等)では問題なくファイルコピー，その後の元ファイル削除ができることを確認しています。

Googleに申請して，EarlyAccessProgramには参加済みです。
またG Suiteビジネスを契約しています。

ファイルサイズ等の問題でエラーが避けられない場合，別の方法でコピーをさせることはできるのでしょうか。
もしくは，エラーを回避する他の方法はあるのでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

```js
function myFunction() {
  var folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("映像");
  var dest = DriveApp.getFolderById('BBB');
  while(folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    folderCopy(folder, dest);
  }
  listtrash();
}

function folderCopy(folder, dest) {
  var folders = folder.getFolders();
  var files = folder.getFiles();

  while(files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    // file.makeCopy(dest);とすると、****のコピーというファイル名になるので…。
    file.makeCopy(file.getName(), dest);
  }

  while(folders.hasNext()) {
    var subFolder = folders.next();
    var folderName = subFolder.getName();
    var copyFolder = dest.createFolder(folderName);
    folderCopy(subFolder, copyFolder);
  }  
}

function listtrash() {
  var removefolders = DriveApp.getFolderById('AAA');
  var removefolder = removefolders.next();
  var subfolders = removefolder.getFolders();
  while(subfolders.hasNext()) {
  var trashFolder = subfolders.next();
  trashFolder.setTrashed(true)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GoogleDrive の無料プランは確か容量が５Gに制限されていますが、コピーの過程でそれに引っかかっているということはないでしょうか

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。G Suiteビジネスを契約しているため，その制限はないと思います。よろしくお願いします。